# How do I recreate a footer that shows details horizontally

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to recreate the footer part of my html so that the details below will appear as per image below on my website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7WFc.png)

```
   <div class="footer-details">
        <h1>Hours<h1>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Monday-Friday</span></li>
          <li>9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</li>
          <li><span>Saturday</span></li>
          <li>10:00 AM - 4:00 PM</li>
          <li><span>Sunday</span></li>
       <li>Closed</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-details">
        <h1>Social</h1>
        <div class="social-links">
       <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><img class="social-logo" src="/Assets/Icons/icon-instagram.png" alt="icon-instagram" width="30px"/></a>
       <a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/"><img class="social-logo" src="/Assets/Icons/icon-facebook.png" alt="icon-facebook" width="30px"/></a>
       <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en-gb"><img class="social-logo" src="/Assets/Icons/icon-twitter.png" alt="icon-twitter" width="30px"/></a>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please update your question adding your code.

Comment: I have added the code, please help

Comment: Your link is not working. Can you please fix that ?

Comment: @seymurium link to what please the image? I have added a new image for example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, include your day and hour period pairs into one `li` tag. Like this:

```
<li>
   <div>Monday-Friday</div>
   <div>9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</div>
</li>
<li>
   <div>Saturday</div>
   <div>10:00 AM - 4:00 PM</div>
</li>
```

Then give `display: flex` to the footer itself, the `ul` tag and the `div` element with `social-links` class.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, I'll just add this link to a [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) just in case.